# Error al abrir Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Instalé Android Studio y al iniciar me muestra este mensaje de error:

> Error launching Android Studio
>
> Failed to create JVM: error code-1.
> JVM Path:C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre
> If you already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable
> in Computer>SystemProperties>System Settings>Environment Variables.

Así es como tengo el entorno de variables.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor explícanos detalladamente tu problema!

Comment: ve si esto soluciona tu problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033231/with-android-studio-no-jvm-found-java-home-has-been-set

Answer (score 4):

El mensaje te indica el problema, instalaste Android Studio para 32 bits pero para esto necesitas [JDK de 32 bits](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), debes instalarlo e indicar dentro de las "Environment variables" el path en la variable "JAVA_HOME".

- Es importante comentar que debes asegurar estar usando un sistema de 32 bits, ya que si instalas y configuras JAVA_HOME con JDK para 32 bits puedes crear problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de Android Studio revisa que tengas definido el path correcto al JDK, puedes acceder mediante

**File** > **Project Structure** > **SDK Location**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenos días Elenasys.

Comment: Buen día, se soluciono el ptoblema?

Comment: Me pidió crear el archivo studio.vmoptions. Pero entonces no me dejaba abrir el Android. Lo borré pero entonces se abría pero me daba el fallo. Estoy desesperado porque no puedo avanzar ni crear mi primera app.El SO que utilizo es windows 10 32 bits y el JDK instalado también es de 32 bits. No entiendo que pasa. Saludos.

Comment: No hay qie desesperarse, hay que agregar todos estos datos en la pregunta. Que esta definido como JAVA_HOME en las variables de entorno? Por lo que veo tienea definido el path del JRE no del JDK

Comment: Hola Elenasys. Voy a ver si puedo colocar una imagen de como tengo las variables de entorno.

Comment: Agregue una actualización, verifica que en tu Android Studio tengas definido el path correcto del JDK que sería : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102